# What exactly is Session, Connection object in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I am new to hibernate and I am confused about this Session object that is bound to the transaction scope of the application. I have read some articles on the internet but I couldn't find any satisfying explanation.
How is this different from Connection Object?

Suppose I have a spring boot application and multiple requests are coming into the server, So how the Session Objects will be created for each new web request And What will happen when I have a connection Pool like c3p0. How is Session getting mapped to the connection object and threads in c3p0 thread pool and the server threads in the Mysql server(database in this case)?
Can someone please explain this in detail?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't the session object just release the connection object but leave the tcp connection managed by the connection pool open so that the next session object can use the open connection?

The session object handling the request data and keeping references to both the JDBC connection it uses and transaction marking the jdbc connection as closed when done. In this way whatever the close() method does with the jdbc connection is not the concern of the session object.